# Create a table with primary key no duplicate

Tags: vb6, key

I'm trying to create a table in MS Access via VB6 connected using ADODB.
Here is my code,

```
dim rs as new ADODB.recordset
set rs = new ADODB.recordset
rs.Open "cretae table (StudentNumber Integer primary key)", con, 3, 3
```

The code works fine, but the StudentNumber column allows duplicate values. I want an error message to pop up if an existing student number is attempted to be re-entered.

Comment: so that's im possible so here's what i did, i used the power of .EOF before saving.

rs1sP1y.Open "select StudentNumber from " & cmbRecords.Text & " where StudentNumber like " & txtAddStudent.Text, con, 3, 3
            If rs1sP1y.EOF Then
            With rs1sP1y
                .AddNew
                .Fields("StudentNumber") = txtAddStudent.Text
                .Update
                .Requery
            End With
            Else
            MsgBox "Student Number Already Added.", vbCritical, "Duplicate Account"
            Exit Sub
            End If

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not "connected using ADODB" you are using ADO.  ADODB is merely one of the two major libraries that make up ADO.

*Talking wrong is thinking wrong, and leads to doing wrong.*

There is no reason to use a Recordset here.  You should also avoid using magic numbers, and ADO provides Enums for nearly everything so there is no excuse to.

```
con.Execute "CREATE TABLE [Students](" _
          & "[StudentNumber] LONG CONSTRAINT [PK_StudentNumber] PRIMARY KEY)", _
            , _
            adCmdText Or adExecuteNoRecords
```

Note that INTEGER, LONG, INT, and INTEGER4 all mean *signed 32-bit integer* in JET SQL.  You can say SMALLINT, SHORT, or INTEGER2 if you want a *signed 16-bit integer*.

Also note that CONSTRAINTs are global database objects and require unique names.

Comment: is it too late now to say i'm sorry? :(

Comment: LOL, it is never too late to *be* sorry and correct your course.  This helps you avoid taking wrong turns in the future.